# Applying Timezone aware to a queryset of objects with datetimes in UTC

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a simple queryset that returns booking objects with a start_time and end_time in utc and have TIME_ZONE set to UTC in settings which I need.
I know how to convert a  single date time object from UTC to local but I'm struggling to apply it to my queryset of booking objects, so I can show a booking list to my users in their dashboard in local time.

```
bookings = Booking.objects.filter(contractor=contractor).order_by('-booking_start')
```

Comment: This is a presentational matter, you should probably do the conversion to local time as late as possible in your code. Are you using a template to show the result, or does this go through an API call, or something else?

Comment: in the template, I have no issue doing the conversion of the time in the Django detail view when dealing with the single object, its the list view where Im showing all bookings and I'm stuck with the UTC times as stored in my database

Comment: Is your problem figuring out how to apply the same template code to a list of results? If so, posting your code here (what you have tried and what you are hoping to achieve) may help others help you better.